# prevent non-logged in users from reading the comments

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have this structure

```
posts : {
    "id" : {
        title : "title" ,
        content : "content" ,
        image : "url" ,
        comments : {
            "commentId" : {
                "name" : "name" ,
                "comment" : "comment" ,
                "time" : 26342624362436
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to prevent non-logged in users from seeing comments of a post but they can see other info (title , content , image)

here are my rules :

```
{
    "rules" : {
        "posts" : {
            "$id" : {
                ".read" : "auth != null"
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

but this will allow only logged in users to read , non-logged users can't read the post info (title , content , image).

can any one help me my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to solve your issue I need to change your structure little bit

```
posts : {
    "$id" : {
        "metaData" : {
            title : "title" ,
            content : "content" ,
            image : "url" ,
        }
        "comments" : {
            "$commentId" : {
                "name" : "name" ,
                "comment" : "comment" ,
                "time" : 26342624362436
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use these rules

```
{
    "rules" : {
        "posts" : {
            "$id" : {
                "metaData" : {
                    ".read" : "true"
                },
                "comments" : {
                    ".read" : "auth != null"
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```